# How to prove these equations? ( theorem in multiresolution analysis)

Tags: wavelets

Suppose $\left \{ V_{j} ; j\in \mathbb{Z} \right \}$ is a multiresolution analysis with scaling function $\varphi$  . then the following scaling relation hold:
$ \varphi (x)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} p_{k}\varphi (2x-k) $
Where
$P_{k}= 2\int_{-\infty }^{\infty}\varphi (x)\overline{\varphi (2x-k)}dx $
Moreover, we also have 
(*)  $\varphi (2^{j-1}x-l)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}p_{k-2l}\varphi (2^jx-k) $
And 
(**)  $\sum p_{k-2l} \overline{p}_{k}= 2\delta_{l0}$

Now, how can I prove (٭) and (**)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let be
$$
\varphi (x)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} p_{k}\varphi (2x-k)\tag 1
$$
where 
$$
p_{k}= 2\int_{-\infty }^{\infty}\varphi (x)\overline{\varphi (2x-k)}\operatorname{d}!x=2\langle \varphi (x), \varphi (2x-k)\rangle\tag 2 
$$
being $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$ the scalar product in $L^2$.

Substituting $x$ with $2^{j-1}x-l$ in (1), we have
$$
\begin{align}
\varphi (2^{j-1}x-l)&=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} p_{k}\varphi \left(2(2^{j-1}x-l)-k\right)\\
&=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} p_{k}\varphi (2^{j}x-(k+2l))\\
&=\sum_{\nu\in \mathbb{Z}} p_{\nu-2l}\varphi (2^{j}x-\nu)\qquad  (k+2l=\nu)
\end{align}
$$
and finally, changing the dummy index $\nu\to k$,
$$\color{red}{(\star)}\qquad\color{blue}{
\varphi (2^{j-1}x-l)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} p_{k-2l}\varphi (2^{j}x-k)}.
$$

The function $\varphi$ belongs to $V_0$ and the set $\{\varphi(x-2k),k\in\Bbb Z\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $V_0$. So we have
$$
\langle \varphi (x-m), \varphi (x-l)\rangle=\delta_{lm}\tag 3
$$
From the (1), substituting $x\to x-l$, we have
$$
\varphi (x-l)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} p_{k}\varphi \left(2x-(k+2l)\right)
$$
Letting $m=0$, we have 
$$\begin{align}
\delta_{l0}&= \langle \varphi (x), \varphi (x-l)\rangle\\
&=\left\langle \varphi (x),\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} p_{k}\varphi\left(2x-(k+2l)\right)\right\rangle\\
&=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} p_{k}\underbrace{\left\langle \varphi (x),\varphi\left(2x-(k+2l)\right)\right\rangle}_{=\frac{1}{2}\bar{p}_{k+2l}\;\text{using the (2)}}\\
&=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} p_{k}\frac{1}{2}\bar{p}_{k+2l}\qquad\text{(put }\nu=k+2l)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} p_{\nu-2l}\bar{p}_{\nu}
\end{align}
$$
and finally replacing the dummy variable $\nu\to k$
$$\color{red}{(\star\star)}\qquad\color{blue}{
\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}} p_{k-2l}\bar{p}_{k}=2\delta_{l0}.}
$$

Comment: Very thanks alexjo. But, Why is your answer(**) differnt to the original equation?

Comment: @ehsanzarei I have just edited the details. You need to change $\nu=k+2l$ and then replace $\nu\to k$.